# Rails - How to order multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to enable users of my app to create online polls which have an arbitrary amount of questions. Questions come in two flavours: multiple choice and open ended

My idea is to build something like this:

```
Poll
  has_many open_question
  has_many multichoice_questions
```

With apropriate `belongs_to` in the associated models.

How do i make it possible to save the order in which questions appear, so that it can be recreated when the poll is taken?

I'm thinking about serializing an ordered 3D array with question id's and types, but that feels wrong (it's saving the same information twice).

What would be a Rails way to model this?

Comment: Include the order in the question model

Comment: @aromero i'm trying to avoid that since it seems like repeating the existing information

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would set up my model like this:

```
User has_many Polls has_many OpenQuestions && MultichoiceQuestions
```

Then I could do something like this:

```
@user = current_user
@poll = @user.polls.find(params[:poll_id])
@open_questions = @poll.open_questions.order('created_at ASC')
```

Alternatively, if you feel you need even more control you could leverage some scopes.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: what i'm trying to do is how to mix in open_questions with multichoice_questions and have their order recorded somehow.